# When creating checkboxes through a loop, only the first one appears

Tags: c#, for-loop, checkbox

I have a list of user defined "tags" stored in a list of strings called warehouse.tags. Using a basic for loop, I am creating checkboxes for each of the tags and adding them to a panel within a windows form.

The problem is that only the first checkbox shows up. I stepped through the code several times, and the location coordinates and other properties seem to be working. The problem does not seem to be that the checkbox location is outside the panel boundaries.

```
   for(int i = 0; i < warehouse.tags.Count; i++) //adds check boxes for each tag
        {
            CheckBox tagNameLabel = new CheckBox();
            tagNameLabel.Text = warehouse.tags.ElementAt(i);
            Point tagLabelPoint = new Point();
            tagLabelPoint.X = xAdjuster; // xadjuster = 25 in this case 
            tagLabelPoint.Y = (5 + yAdjuster) * (warehouse.categories.Count + 1); //yadjuster = 25 as well
            tagNameLabel.Location = tagLabelPoint;
            this.filterOptionsPanel.Controls.Add(tagNameLabel);

        }
```

Open to any ideas of what may be going wrong - thanks.

Comment: Your Y coordinate is always set to the same value, so you're ending up with a bunch of controls stacked on top of one another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that all your checkboxes will be set to the same location.

```
tagLabelPoint.X = xAdjuster; // xadjuster = 25 in this case 
tagLabelPoint.Y = (5 + yAdjuster) * (warehouse.categories.Count + 1);
```

Since you are not using `i` in this formula every checkbox will be set to the same position. Note that `yAdjuster` and `warehouse.categories.Count` will never change through the looping process.

Comment: That means you should probably do `tagLabelPoint.Y = (5 + yAdjuster) * (i + 1);`.

Comment: I am guessing 5 is an offset from the top, so my solution would have been `5 + yAdjuster * (i + 1)`.

Comment: Thanks!! Andrew that solved it. And yes, Ian that suggested code worked. Appreciate the quick answer.